# How should I parse an ISO date in expl3?

Tags: expl3, datetime

Assuming `date` is ISO-formatted (`YYYY-MM-DD`), how can I parse out its individual parts into variables?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \mytest_date_day_int
\int_new:N \mytest_date_month_int
\int_new:N \mytest_date_year_int

\keys_define:nn { note-verbale } {
  date .code:n = { },           % ???
}

\NewDocumentCommand \Information { m } {
  \keys_set:nn { note-verbale } { #1 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \PrintDate { } {
  Date:\nobreakspace

  \int_use:N \mytest_date_day_int
  \slash
  \int_use:N \mytest_date_month_int
  \slash
  \int_use:N \mytest_date_year_int
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\Information{
  date = 2015-02-10,
}

\begin{document}
\PrintDate 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think there's a duplicate out there.

Comment: @Manuel You would think, but a search for `expl3 iso date` yields nil.

Comment: @Manuel I suppose it's possible such a duplicate wouldn't mention `expl3`.

Comment: It's bugging me, I think it was intended to be parsed exactly like this, with expl3 involved. And I think the asker was A.Ellet, but may be my memory is wrong, I can't find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Improving on your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \mytest_date_day_int
\int_new:N \mytest_date_month_int
\int_new:N \mytest_date_year_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mytest_date_parse:n #1
 {
  \__mytest_date_parse:www #1 \q_stop
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mytest_date_parse:www #1-#2-#3 \q_stop
 {
  \int_set:Nn \mytest_date_year_int  {#1}
  \int_set:Nn \mytest_date_month_int {#2}
  \int_set:Nn \mytest_date_day_int   {#3}
 }

\keys_define:nn { my-test } {
  date .code:n = { \mytest_date_parse:n { #1 } },
}

\NewDocumentCommand \Information { m } {
  \keys_set:nn { my-test } { #1 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \PrintDate { } {
  Date:\nobreakspace

  \int_use:N \mytest_date_day_int
  \slash
  \int_use:N \mytest_date_month_int
  \slash
  \int_use:N \mytest_date_year_int
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\Information{
  date = 2015-02-10,
}

\begin{document}
\PrintDate 
\end{document}
```

It's better to split off the `.code:n` bit with the actual implementation. There's no need to define the parser macro with six arguments, as three are predetermined.

Don't forget that functions performing assignments should be `protected`.

Here's a check that the date is in ISO format: YYYY-MM-DD (but it allows month and year to be one digit); `l3regex` is the easiest tool. In case the date is invalid, `0/0/0` is printed, but it is easy to add a suitable error message.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \mytest_date_day_int
\int_new:N \mytest_date_month_int
\int_new:N \mytest_date_year_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mytest_date_parse:n #1
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { \A \d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \Z } { #1 }
   {
    \__mytest_date_parse:www #1 \q_stop
   }
   {
    \__mytest_date_parse:www 0000-00-00 \q_stop
   }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__mytest_date_parse:www #1-#2-#3 \q_stop
 {
  \int_set:Nn \mytest_date_year_int  {#1}
  \int_set:Nn \mytest_date_month_int {#2}
  \int_set:Nn \mytest_date_day_int   {#3}
 }

\keys_define:nn { my-test } {
  date .code:n = { \mytest_date_parse:n {#1} },
}

\NewDocumentCommand \Information { m } {
  \keys_set:nn { my-test } { #1 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \PrintDate { } {
  Date:\nobreakspace

  \int_use:N \mytest_date_day_int
  \slash
  \int_use:N \mytest_date_month_int
  \slash
  \int_use:N \mytest_date_year_int
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\Information{
  date = 2015-02-10,
}

\begin{document}
\PrintDate 

\Information{date=201-1-1}
\PrintDate

\Information{date=2015-1}
\PrintDate

\Information{date=2015/1/1}
\PrintDate

\end{document}
```

The regex means: the entire string (`\A` and `\Z` represent start and end) should consist of four digits (`\d{4}`), a hyphen, one to two digits `\d{1,2}`, a hyphen and again one to two digits. Any other format will return false.

---

A further version that accepts also `date=20150101`, that is a string of eight digits and splits the parsing into the two cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \mytest_date_day_int
\int_new:N \mytest_date_month_int
\int_new:N \mytest_date_year_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mytest_date_validate_parse:n #1
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { \A \d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \Z } { #1 }
   {
    \__mytest_date_parse:www #1 \q_stop
   }
   {
    \regex_match:nnTF { \A \d{8} \Z } { #1 }
     {
      \__mytest_date_parse:nnnnnnnn #1
     }
     {
      \__mytest_date_parse:nnnnnnnn 00000000
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__mytest_date_parse:www #1-#2-#3 \q_stop
 {
  \int_set:Nn \mytest_date_year_int  {#1}
  \int_set:Nn \mytest_date_month_int {#2}
  \int_set:Nn \mytest_date_day_int   {#3}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__mytest_date_parse:nnnnnnnn
 {
  \int_set:Nn \mytest_date_year_int  {#1#2#3#4}
  \int_set:Nn \mytest_date_month_int {#5#6}
  \int_set:Nn \mytest_date_day_int   {#7#8}
 }

\keys_define:nn { my-test } {
  date .code:n = { \mytest_date_validate_parse:n {#1} },
}

\NewDocumentCommand \Information { m } {
  \keys_set:nn { my-test } { #1 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \PrintDate { } {
  Date:\nobreakspace

  \int_use:N \mytest_date_day_int
  \slash
  \int_use:N \mytest_date_month_int
  \slash
  \int_use:N \mytest_date_year_int
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\Information{
  date = 2015-02-10,
}

\begin{document}
Good: \PrintDate 

\Information{date=201-1-1}%bad
Bad: \PrintDate

\Information{date=2015-1}%bad
Bad: \PrintDate

\Information{date=2015/1/1}%bad
Bad: \PrintDate

\Information{date=20150101}%good
Good: \PrintDate

\Information{date=201511}%bad
Bad: \PrintDate

\Information{date=201501012}%bad
Bad: \PrintDate

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think I'd want a defensive part in case the `-` tokens have gone AWOL!

Comment: Didn't know about `protected` stuff – is there a section in `texdoc interface3` that goes over this?

Comment: @SeanAllred In the style guide: http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/l3styleguide.pdf

Comment: @egreg Didn't you answer something *quite* similar with an `\seq_` approach? With David giving a plainTeX solution?

Comment: @JosephWright Also available via `texdoc l3styleguide`.  I wish I'd known about this sooner – I'll give it a read through :)

Comment: @JosephWright I added a validation with a regular expression, which in this case seems the best tool.

Comment: @Manuel Probably so; here I added a validation step that allows to be sure about scanning the given date with delimited parameters.

Comment: @SeanAllred We are planning to try to give a new overview for LaTeX3 docs: I'll make sure the style guide is included.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a parser function and introduce a quark in the `date .code:n`.  Note that the quark `\q_stop` is used to delimit the length of the last argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \mytest_date_day_int
\int_new:N \mytest_date_month_int
\int_new:N \mytest_date_year_int

\cs_new:Npn \mytest_date_parse:wNNN #1-#2-#3 \q_stop #4 #5 #6
 {
  \int_set:Nn #4 {#1}
  \int_set:Nn #5 {#2}
  \int_set:Nn #6 {#3}
 }

\keys_define:nn { my-test } {
  date .code:n = {
  \mytest_date_parse:wNNN
    #1 \q_stop
    \mytest_date_day_int
    \mytest_date_month_int
    \mytest_date_year_int
  },
}

\NewDocumentCommand \Information { m } {
  \keys_set:nn { my-test } { #1 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \PrintDate { } {
  Date:\nobreakspace

  \int_use:N \mytest_date_day_int
  \slash
  \int_use:N \mytest_date_month_int
  \slash
  \int_use:N \mytest_date_year_int
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\Information{
  date = 2015-02-10,
}

\begin{document}
\PrintDate 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I'd want a defensive part in case the - tokens have gone AWOL!

Comment: @JosephWright As if the user said `date = 20150210`?

Comment: which is of course a valid ISO format date

Comment: @SeanAllred Or anything else, but yes: you've not tested for `-` tokens!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Huh – turns out [you're absolutely right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates).  I had always thought ISO was unambiguous for some of these bigger things, but I suppose the indecision runs through and through.

Comment: @JosephWright Then some sort of check needs to be put in place that the string given actually *matches* some regular expression. At that point, it would actually be pretty simple just to kill the delimited parsing and just take the date digit by digit.

Comment: @SeanAllred I've added this bit.